# LIMIT is not working in my query

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
( SELECT count( city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station ) 
- ( SELECT count(DISTINCT city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station ) AS sub_value
 FROM station
```

which works fine, but when I added `LIMIT 1` in query it is not working

```
SELECT 
( SELECT count( city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station ) 
- ( SELECT count(DISTINCT city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station ) AS sub_value
 FROM station LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Can you attach the error you're getting?

Comment: That is not correct, `limit 1` takes only the first result.

Comment: Can't you try this query:- SELECT (count(1) -  count(DISTINCT city)) sub_value from station

Comment: In what way does it not work? Do you get an error message? Does it return values, but different to the ones you would expect? If so, how does it differ from the expected output?

Comment: ERROR - command not properly ended

Answer (score 6):

Try This query:-

```
SELECT (count(city) - count(DISTINCT city)) sub_value from station
```

Comment: Good insight to get rid of the unnecessary `sub-queries`.

Comment: @1000111 why did `you` use `code formatting` for "sub-queries"?

Comment: The comment is immutable now. By the way, can I ask you the same question? :p (#Nevermind) @JanDvorak

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the OFFSET as well

```
FROM station LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

Also it looks like you are trying to find the difference between the count of rows between total no of city and distinct no of city so you can instead try to get the result as:

```
SELECT count( city) - count(DISTINCT city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station
```

In this case you dont need to use the LIMIT since the result would be a single value.(*Very similar to what Rakesh posted in his answer.*)

Comment: @bhuwan:- Can you define `not working`? Is it giving some error?

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
SELECT sub_value from
((SELECT count( city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station) - (SELECT count(DISTINCT city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station)) AS sub_value limit 1
```

Otherwise:
you can use left join like this:

```
select count1-count2 AS RESULT from
(select count(encode) as count1 from tbl_ranking) AS A
LEFT JOIN
(select count(EnName) AS count2 from tbl_ranking) as B 

ON A.ID = B.ID LIMIT 1
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here you don't need to use **from station** in last where you are using subqueries for same table.

I have the following MySQL query:

SELECT 
( SELECT count( city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station ) 
- ( SELECT count(DISTINCT city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station ) AS sub_value
 FROM station

which works fine, but when I added LIMIT 1 in query it is not working

```
SELECT
( SELECT count( city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station ) 
- ( SELECT count(DISTINCT city) as no_off_total_cityies FROM station ) AS sub_value;
```

Try this. Hope this help.